# ParticlesJS: "Uncaught ReferenceError: particlesJS is not defined"

Tags: particles.js

We had ParticlesJS working @ https://digital.insightdesign.com.au/, overlaying the full width/height image slider in the first section below the header.

However, it stopped working today with no changes made to the site.

The console says: `Uncaught ReferenceError: particlesJS is not defined`

We are calling:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js" defer data-deferred="1"></script>
```

(on line 44 of the website).

There are no resources generating a 404, and no other JS errors in console.

Help appreciated.

Comment: try changing the cdn to this: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/particles.js@2.0.0/particles.min.js. even though your cdn is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove `defer` from:

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js" defer data-deferred="1"></script>
```

or add the `particlesJS` code inside a `DOMContentLoaded` event like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  /* ---- particles.js config ---- */

  particlesJS("particles-js", {
    "particles": {
      "number": {
        "value": 380,
        "density": {
          "enable": true,
          "value_area": 3600
        }
      },
      ...
    }
    ...
  });
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

> **defer**
>
> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the
>   script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but
>   before firing DOMContentLoaded.
>
> Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the DOMContentLoaded
>   event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating.
>
> This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e.
>   for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect.
>
> Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which
>   they appear in the document.